# Replacing null values in PHP array

Tags: php, sql, foreach, null

A common question, but other answers aren't always clear, so I apologise if this has cropped up elsewhere a million times.

Simple; I have null values returning in my array from a query, I want to cycle through and replace them with zero. I've been trying with the following code;

```
$stat = $db->getUserStats($id, $code, $mod1, $mod2);    
        foreach ($stat as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == null) {
                $value = 0;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a reference:

```
foreach ($stat as $key => &$value) {
```

The `$value` you currently have in `if ($value == null)` is not the actual array value, but a copy created by `foreach`.

You should also use a strict `null` check: `if ($value === null)`

You should unset the reference after the `foreach` loop. (See the **Warning** box in the [foreach documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).)

---

Another possible way to accomplish this is to use an expression in your query to returns zeroes instead of nulls. That will vary depending on which database you're using.